# Check item membership in set in Python

Tags: python, set

Hello I've been coding for a couple of months now and know the basics, but I'm having a set membership problem for which I can't find a solution.

I have a list of lists of pairs of integers, and I want to remove the list that have the "a" integer in them. I thought using sets was the easiest way. Bellow is the code:

```
## This is the item to test against. 
a = set([3]) 
## This is the list to test.      
groups = [[3, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 4], [4, 3]]     

## This is a list that will contain the lists present
## in groups which do not contain "a"
groups_no_a = []        

for group in groups:
    group = set(group)
    if a in group:
        groups_no_a.append(group)
    ## I thought the problem had something to do with
    ## clearing the variable so I put this in,   
    ## but to no remedy. 
    group.clear()  


print groups_no_a
```

I had also tried using **`s.issubset(t)`** until I realized that this tested if ***every*** element in *`s`* in *`t`*.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You want to test if there is no [*intersection*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
if not a & group:
```

or

```
if not a.intersection(group):
```

or, inversely, that the sets are [*disjoint*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint):

```
if a.isdisjoint(group):
```

The method forms take *any* iterable, you don't even have to turn `group` into a set for that. The following one-liner would work too:

```
groups_no_a = [group for group in groups if a.isdisjoint(group)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = set([3]) 
>>> groups = [[3, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 4], [4, 3]]     
>>> [group for group in groups if a.isdisjoint(group)]
[[1, 2], [5, 4]]
```

If all you are testing for is **one** element, then it could be that creating sets is going to cost more in performance than what you gain in testing for membership, and just doing:

```
3 not in group
```

where `group` is a short list.

You can use the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to compare pieces of Python code to see what works best for your specific typical list sizes.

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood the question, for what he wants to do, he doesn't need sets. It looks like he just wants to find if an element is in a list, and decided that sets were the way to do this, even though they aren't.

Comment: @user2387370: And sets are faster for that task; `one_element in somelist` has to scan the list.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the disjoint option as it's a bit hidden in  [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Comment: @grasshopper: that is the deprecated module, from before `set` was added as a type to the language.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". I doubt using sets would have been suggested if the question had just been "how to check if an element is in a list". In any case, I doubt how great any increase in performance is, as you are only checking for membership in a list of 2 items.

Comment: @user2387370: And perhaps the OP just simplified the cases down to very small subsets. Without the OP feedback on that we don't know.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The presence of comments suggests this is actual code. In any case, would you have mentioned sets if the question had just been "How to check the presence of an element in a list?"

Comment: @user2387370: yes, depending on the context. If the test is repeated for different values (say, lines in a file), then a set would be a much better choice.

Comment: @user2387370: as for the comments, those clarify the question. They don't strike me as part of production code. I've seen loads of question askers do that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The most common case of testing for membership is for small lists, where `in` and `not in` are appropriate. Therefore, I would say that should be the main focus of an answer, with sets mentioned more briefly, reflecting the use of both methods. However, your answer is the opposite.

Comment: Well to those curious, what I want to do is; I have a list like the following: [ [error, [ [group_item_1, group_item_2], [...], [...], [...] ] ], [more like this previous], [...]  ], and I want to get the item with least error and that doesn't have "a" in group_item_1 or group_item_2. The lists are already sorted by error.     I sorta almost go it :D

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could use [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a = 3
groups = [[3, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 4], [4, 3]]
print [x for x in groups if a not in x]
```

Edit based on a comment:

> Well to those curious, what I want to do is; I have a list like the
>   following: [ [error, [ [group_item_1, group_item_2], [...], [...],
>   [...] ] ], [more like this previous], [...] ], and I want to get the
>   item with least error and that doesn't have "a" in group_item_1 or
>   group_item_2. The lists are already sorted by error. I sorta almost go
>   it :D

This should do the trick:

```
from itertools import chain, iterfilter

def flatten(listOfLists):
    "Flatten one level of nesting"
    return chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)


errors_list =  [ ['error0', [ [30, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 4], [4, 3] ] ], ['error1', [ [31, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 4], [4, 3] ] ] ]

a = 30
result = next(ifilter(lambda err: a not in flatten(err[1]), reversed(errors_list)), None)

print result #finds error1 as it has no 30 on its list
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making a = set([3]), why not do the following?

```
a = 3
groups = [[3, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 4], [4, 3]]
groups_no_a = [group for group in groups if a not in group]
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use sets here, you can test for membership of elements in lists. You also seem to have `in`, where I think you should have `not in`.

This code is similar to yours, and should work:

```
## This is the item to test against. 
a = 3
## This is the list to test.      
groups = [[3, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 4], [4, 3]]     

## This is a list that will contain the lists present
## in groups which do not contain a
groups_no_a = []        

for group in groups:
    if a not in group:
        groups_no_a.append(group)

print groups_no_a
```

However, a shorter, more Pythonic way uses [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
groups_no_a = [i for i in groups if a not in i]
```

If you are testing a whether an item is in a much longer list, you should use sets instead for performance.